# How to handle configuration transforms of WebRole in VSTS Release Definition

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have a Web role which is deployed by a Cloud Service project and I have a build and release definition setup to deploy to 2 environments (Staging and Production.) My goal is to have a Staging and Production connection string in their respective environments, but I'm curious as to how this can work with a release definition that refers to a single build artifact.

So far I have a Web.Staging.config and a Web.Production.config - with Build action set to "Content" and Copy Always.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is build and publish cloud service project during release:

1. Create a new build definition
2. Add Publish Build Artifacts task (Path to publish: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)
3. Create a new release and associate to that build
4. Add necessary variables for each environment, for example: Name=`BuildConfiguration`; Value=`Staging`; Scope=`StagingEnv` (environment name); Name=`BuildConfiguration`; Value=`Production`; Scope=`ProductionEnv` (environment name);
5. Add Visual Studio build tasks to each environment of release definition to build and publish cloud service project (Configuration: `$(BuildConfiguration)`)

BTW, you can add Git artifact in release definition directly if you are using git.

Comment: is there a task to do token replacement, similar to variables transform of octopus?

Comment: @4c74356b41 There are many tasks: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=token&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance. You also can do it with custom script.

Comment: nothing built-in? i know i can do it with script, this also means I might as well do it with octopus instead of vsts

Comment: @4c74356b41 No built-in token replace task for this requirement